# Identifying (spoken) language in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

Does anyone know if there is any language detection script/library available for javascript? I like to incorporate it into nodejs but didn't found any.

I don't want a browser language detection but a string language detection.
'Hello World' would be detected english and 'Hallo Wereld' would be detected as dutch.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that big into natural language processing but I suppose you could use [Trigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram).

ActiveState has a [Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/326576-language-detection-using-character-trigrams/) of a simple Python version.

Of course you can always use a C++ library and write a wrapper for Node.js and compile that.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Translate API allows language detection and works with JavaScript. You should check out the reference below:

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/reference.html

Comment: Thanks, but that way I have to send a request everytime I want to detect a language. And that would happen a lot. The best way is a local library with a backend database (possible because I use nodejs)

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know of any language detection libraries that can be run locally. The only suggestion I can offer is using navigator.language to try and detect the user's language from the browser settings.